# VBA UserForm finding nth value from textboxes

Tags: vba

I have created a userform and 6 textboxes and a button. I need to find first, second and third biggest value.

```
userform name: uform1
testboxes name: t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6
```

I want to recive a message such as "t4 contains first biggest value which is 15, t2 contains second biggest value which is 12, t5 contains tirth biggest value which is 10"

I have checked some codes but I couldn't find solution for textbox values. I have tried the code below but no use.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim Hrdlr As Integer
    Hrdlr = Array(.t1, .t2, .t3, .t4, .t5, .t6)

    Scnd = WorksheetFunction.Large(Hrdlr, 2)
End Sub
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

got an answer, works fine for me.

```
Dim Hrdlr
    Hrdlr = Array(Val(t1.Value), Val(t2.Value), Val(t3.Value), Val(t4.Value))

    Label1.Caption = WorksheetFunction.Large(Hrdlr, 2) & " in t" & Application.Match(WorksheetFunction.Large(Hrdlr, 2), Hrdlr, False)
```